# What is the problem in proving $\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ in purely algebraic method

Tags: abstract-algebra, transcendental-numbers

Why can’t we prove for the field extension $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ ,$\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ in a purely algebraic method? Or is there any prove that proves $\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ in a purely algebraic method?

Comment: what do you mean by "trascendental over $\mathbb{Q}$ algebraically"?

Comment: @Guillerminho77 i wanted to say in purely algebraic method,  only using concept of algebra

Comment: Most, possibly all definitions of $\pi$ need some calculus, so it looks like a matter of which concepts of calculus you don't like.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Why all definition of $\pi$ need some calculus? All the definitions of $\pi$ comes the from the concept of distance, and the embedding of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Its feels suffocating

Comment: @Epsilon101 You're right, I cannot back my statement up. Let's rephrase it: I don't know of one. Feel free to name a definition of $\pi$ that uses no calculus.

Comment: In some sense, the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental is itself a hint that there can't be a purely "algebraic" proof (depending of course on what you mean by "algebraic").  There's no way to get at $\pi$ by just talking about finite sequences of elementary algebraic operations like $+, -, *, /$ and extracting roots. To define $\pi$ you have to have something like a limit notion.

Comment: Even the classical, geometric definition of $\pi$ as a number uses the method of exhaustion, which is basically a geometric precursor to limits/cauchy sequences, for which I know no purely algebraic version.

Comment: As I have mentioned elsewhere, given any two transcendental numbers $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ over $\mathbb Q$, we have that the fields $\mathbb Q( \alpha_1)$ and $\mathbb Q( \alpha_2)$ are isomorphic. So all transcendental numbers are algebraically indistinguishable from the point of view of $\mathbb Q$.